# Paste as Text and Keep Leading Zero

Tags: excel, vba

How to Paste as Text and Keep leading zero. I am trying to convert this code to paste as text rather than value but it keeps giving me an error.

Your help will be much appreciated.

I want to keep the `0` using my below function.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0huuJ.png]

```
Set rngA = .NumberFormat = "@"
```

then tried

```
If ra = 1 Then rngB.Resize(, rc).Value = rngA.PasteSpecial : Exit Sub
```

but nothing worked

```
Dim rngA        As Range
    Dim rngB        As Range
    Dim r           As Range
    Dim Title       As String
    Dim ra          As Long
    Dim rc          As Long
    
    On Error GoTo skip:
    
    Title = "Copy Visible To Visible"
    Set rngA = Application.Selection
    Set rngA = Application.InputBox("Select Range To Copy Then click OK:", Title, rngA.Address, Type:=8)
   
    
    Set rngB = Application.InputBox("Select Range To Paste (select the first cell only):", Title, Type:=8)
    Set rngB = rngB.Cells(1, 1)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ra = rngA.Rows.Count
    rc = rngA.Columns.Count
    If ra = 1 Then rngB.Resize(, rc).Value = rngA.Value: Exit Sub
    
    Set rngA = rngA.Cells(1, 1).Resize(ra, 1)
    
    For Each r In rngA.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rngB.Resize(1, rc).Value = r.Resize(1, rc).Value
        Do
            Set rngB = rngB.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop Until rngB.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Next
    
    Application.GoTo rngB
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Exit Sub
skip:
    If Err.Number <> 424 Then
        MsgBox "Error found: " & Err.Description
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: When you do `rngB.Resize(1, rc).Value = r.Resize(1, rc).Value` Excel recognises strings that look like numbers, and "helpfully" converts them to numbers. Precedng the string with a `'` enters the value as a string, and avoids the conversion (as @Skin 's answer demonstrates)

Comment: Besides keeping the format of the *"source"* data (i.e., retaining the leading zeros), the posted code is also dealing with `xlCellTypeVisible`. However, hidden  can not be recognized in the posted picture. Would you please, post a picture showing the headings (rows and columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
rngB.Resize(1, rc).Value = r.Resize(1, rc).Value
```

to this:

```
With rngB.Resize(1, rc)
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = r.Resize(1, rc).Value
End With
```

**Edit #1**

Your code suggests that you only skip hidden rows but ignore any hidden columns. It's faster to copy larger arrays in one go and if there is no hidden row then we don't need to read/write row by row.

I would replace this:

```
ra = rngA.Rows.Count
rc = rngA.Columns.Count
If ra = 1 Then rngB.Resize(, rc).Value = rngA.Value: Exit Sub

Set rngA = rngA.Cells(1, 1).Resize(ra, 1)

For Each r In rngA.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rngB.Resize(1, rc).NumberFormat = "@"
    rngB.Resize(1, rc).Value = r.Resize(1, rc).Value
    Do
        Set rngB = rngB.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop Until rngB.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Next
```

with this:

```
If rngA.Areas.Count > 1 Then Set rngA = rngA.Areas(1)
ra = rngA.Rows.Count
rc = rngA.Columns.Count
Set rngB = rngB.Resize(1, rc)

Dim i As Long: i = 0
Dim firstVisibleRow As Long: firstVisibleRow = 0
Dim lastVisibleRow As Long: lastVisibleRow = 0
Dim rCount As Long
Dim rngWrite As Range
Dim rngRead As Range
Dim isHidden As Boolean

For Each r In rngA.Rows
    i = i + 1
    isHidden = r.EntireRow.Hidden
    If Not isHidden Then
        If lastVisibleRow = 0 Then firstVisibleRow = i
        lastVisibleRow = i
    End If
    If isHidden Or i = ra Then
        If lastVisibleRow > 0 Then
            Set rngWrite = rngB.Rows(firstVisibleRow)
            If lastVisibleRow > firstVisibleRow Then
                rCount = lastVisibleRow - firstVisibleRow + 1
                Set rngWrite = rngWrite.Resize(rCount)
                Set rngRead = r.Resize(rCount).Offset(-rCount + IIf(isHidden, 0, 1))
            ElseIf isHidden Then
                Set rngRead = rngA.Rows(i - 1)
            Else
                Set rngRead = r
            End If
            rngWrite.NumberFormat = "@"
            rngWrite.Value = rngRead.Value
        End If
    End If
    If isHidden Then lastVisibleRow = 0
Next r
```

The code is longer but more efficient.

Comment: That's the way +). - Side note: Think it suffices to write **`rngB.NumberFormat = "@"`** before the code line `rngB.Resize(1, rc).Value = r.Resize(1, rc).Value`. - Afaik it's not necessary to apply the number formatting to the resized `rngB` as it has already the NumberFormat `"@"`. @CristianBuse

Comment: I voted you up as well, meant to do it before actually.  Very nice approach.

Comment: @T.M. Thanks! Added a more efficient approach under **Edit #1**

Comment: Thank you very much sorry for being late reply. Its working perfect.

Comment: It works on more than 1 values not on sinlge value @Cristian Buse The long code parts does work but not small part `With and End with` statement

Comment: @ShRa That's because the ```With``` block is never reached. You have separate logic for one row in the line ```If ra = 1 Then rngB.Resize(, rc).Value = rngA.Value: Exit Sub``` which I've completely removed in the longer version. The inital short answer was just a quick response hence I came back later when I had more time and added the longer response.

Comment: Ok no problem. thank you once again.

Answer (score 4):

Change this ...

```
rngB.Resize(1, rc).Value = r.Resize(1, rc).Value
```

... to this ...

```
rngB.Resize(1, rc).Value = "'" & r.Resize(1, rc).Value
```

Adding an apostrophe in front will instruct Excel to ignore what it thinks it should do for you and will preserve it's textual value and represent it as a string.

I can imagine you will have done this before in a cell manually.  This also works in VBA and is a nice, easy way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, fair call.

Comment: You must first check if the source value already contains ' in front. Because with each copy you can add more unnecessary quotes e.g. this ```'001``` can turn into ```''''001```

Comment: @CristianBuse, I just tested that and there's no issue, it recognises it as a special character and still behaves correctly.

Comment: Forgot that, when reading the value, Excel removes the '. You are correct. Apologies for not checking first

Comment: @CristianBuse, all good ...!  I actually really like your answer.  I guess it's a trade off between having a text formatted cell vs one that can morph between different formats if you want to change the value in the future.  Whatever the OP wants I guess.

Comment: I actually use your approach in all my code. I never rely on the format because it's just too dangerous. +1 from me. But I never work with single cells, my code always uses entire arrays to read/write from/to ranges.

Comment: this also works great Thank you.